# I am getting an index out of range error

Tags: class, python-3.x, object

My function takes a table of the form dictionary and returns the table after applying the query which the person asked. I have several other methods but I am having trouble with the equal condition method . This is what I've tried.

```
class Table():

def where_con(self,table,conditions):
    for condition in conditions:
        if ('='in condition):
            print(table.get_dict())
            print(condition)
            self = table.equal_condition(table,condition)
            return(self) 

        elif('>'in condition):
            new_table = table.greater_condition(table, condition)
            return(self)           

def equal_condition(self,table,condition):
    '''(Table, string) -> Table
    This Function takes in a table and a condition and applies the 
    condition and returns a new table with the condition applied 
    REQ: Table must have the contents of the condition
    REQ: The condition must have proper syntax
    REQ: The condition must contain the equal sign in string form 
    '''
    number_rows = table.num_rows()
    print(number_rows)
    dictionary = table.get_dict()
    print(dictionary)
    condition = condition.split('=')
    print(condition)
    #new_table = Table()
    # Adding Coloums Name in Self 
    for col in dictionary:
        self.add_column({col: []})

    # If the Second part is a string    
    if ("'" in condition[1]):
        condition[1] = condition[1].strip("'")  
        i=0
        while(i<number_rows):
            print(i)
            i=i+1
            if (dictionary[condition[0]][i] == condition[1]):
                for key in self.get_dict():
                    self = self.update_column(key,dictionary[key][i])
            #i=i+1
    else:
        i=0
        while(i<number_rows):
            print(i)
            if (dictionary[condition[0]][i] == dictionary[condition[1]][i]):
                for key in self.get_dict():
                    self.update_column(key,dictionary[key][i])
            i=i+1

    return self
```

So when I give an input as

```
>>>a = Table()
>>>a.set_dict({'w.critic_rating': ['5', '5', '5', '5'], 'o.for':     ['Directing', 'Acting', 'Directing', 'Acting'], 'w.title': ['Titanic', 'Titanic', 'Avatar', 'Avatar'], 'o.title': ['Avatar', 'Titanic', 'Avatar', 'Titanic'], 'w w.your_rating': ['4.5', '4.5', '5', '5'], 'w.average_rating': ['4.75', '4.75',  '5', '5']})
>>>d = Table()
>>>f = where_con(a,"w.title=o.title")
4
{'o.for': ['Directing', 'Acting', 'Directing', 'Acting'], 'o.title': ['Avatar', 'Titanic', 'Avatar', 'Titanic'], 'w.critic_rating': ['5', '5', '5', '5'], 'w.your_rating': ['4.5', '4.5', '5', '5'], 'w.average_rating': ['4.75', '4.75', '5', '5'], 'w.title': ['Titanic', 'Titanic', 'Avatar', 'Avatar']}
['w.title', 'o.title']
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Desktop\MAde_answer\database.py", line 205, in    <module>
if (dictionary[condition[0]][i] == dictionary[condition[1]][i]):
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your Table object has no attribute 'set_dict'? Also num_rows() doesn't seem to be defined

Comment: Your code here is not complete: 'update_column' definition is also missing